# How to resolve the error Attempted import error: 'react-hook-form' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useForm'). using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to Attempted import error: 'react-hook-form' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useForm'). fix the error using react js. I am try to do that but i am getting error when i run nom start this error 'react-hook-form' does not contain a default export (imported as 'useForm'). fix the error using react js.

anybody help me out how to fix that.its very thankful

my code

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useForm from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm({});
  const password = useRef({});
  const newpassword = useRef({});

  password.current = watch("password", "");
  newpassword.current = watch("password_repeat", "");
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    if (password.current.length === 0) {
      alert("You must specify a password");
      return;
    }

    var match = password.current.match(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=[^!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?=\D*\d)/
    );
    if (!match) {
      alert(
        "Password Should contain at least one Number, one upperCase and one lowercase letter and a special character"
      );
      return;
    }

    if (password.current.length < 8) {
      alert("Password must have at least 8 characters");
      return;
    }

    if (newpassword.current !== password.current) {
      alert("The passwords do not match");
      return;
    }

    alert("Your Success message");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input name="password" type="text" ref={register({})} />
      {errors.password && <p>{errors.password.message}</p>}

      <label>Repeat password</label>
      <input name="password_repeat" type="password" ref={register({})} />
      {errors.password_repeat && <p>{errors.password_repeat.message}</p>}

      <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-hook-form-password-match-check-standard-validation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-hook-form": "3.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: anyone help me out???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it has a named export. Therefore, you have to import it as follows.

`import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';`

Refer the following documentation to use `react-hook-form` node module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form

And update the component as follows based on the documentation.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
  } = useForm();
  const password = useRef({});
  const newpassword = useRef({});

  password.current = watch("password", "");
  newpassword.current = watch("password_repeat", "");
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    if (password.current.length === 0) {
      alert("You must specify a password");
      return;
    }

    var match = password.current.match(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=[^!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?=\D*\d)/
    );
    if (!match) {
      alert(
        "Password Should contain at least one Number, one upperCase and one lowercase letter and a special character"
      );
      return;
    }

    if (password.current.length < 8) {
      alert("Password must have at least 8 characters");
      return;
    }

    if (newpassword.current !== password.current) {
      alert("The passwords do not match");
      return;
    }

    alert("Your Success message");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input {...register("password")} />
      {errors.password && <p>{errors.password.message}</p>}

      <label>Repeat password</label>
      <input {...register("password_repeat")} />
      {errors.password_repeat && <p>{errors.password_repeat.message}</p>}

      <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Application View**

[image]

**Code SandBox**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hook-form-password-match-check-standard-validation-forked-lw641?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Update your `package.json` file for dependency used in `react-hook-form` as well.

```
"react-hook-form": "^7.15.0"
```

instead of using `"react-hook-form": "3.13.1"`

Hope this would solve your issue.

Comment: when i run after update getting this error TypeError: path.split is not a function

Comment: Can you provide the complete error log ? It seems that previous error was fixed, but this is something not relevant to module imports.

Comment: when i run npm start in terminal its show compiled successfully but when open in browser its getting error

Comment: https://ibb.co/Z1YkMFw can u plz check this error snaps

Comment: can you please check image sanpshot of error and help me out

Comment: Yes, I just ran it locally and found the same issue. I'm checking it now.

Comment: Thanks for checking if u got any solution please let me know.

Comment: are you checking

Comment: Hope this would solve your issue ? Please check it and let's know.

Comment: thanks i will check and i will let u know

Comment: can u run this code locally u got the result??

Comment: because when i run this npm start its compiled successfully but i am getting in browser white screen only why?? no error only white screen

Comment: Can you check the dev tools console logs ?

Comment: in console getting see the image https://ibb.co/d7fJHsh

Comment: and when i m going log.js in console see the image https://ibb.co/C91Bg5v

Comment: For local running I didn't import styles or react-dom. Now I updated the code and also put the code-sandbox as well. And update your `package.json` file for relevant version of the dependency as I given in the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please kindly put the green tick for the answer to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am add 'use client' in next js and it worked.